# Can any vertex of an isosceles triangle represent the centre of a circle, and the base vertices represent points on the circumference of that circle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

This question occurred to me doing this circle geometry problem, and I was wondering if anyone could clear it up. Geometrically, it seems it would make sense, provided that 2 sides are equal (equal radii), but I am still unsure.

[image]

I specifically refer to triangle ABC. Since BC=AC, is it possible that another circle can be formed about the centre C with radius AC (or BC), like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can form that circle, and it will have the properties you ask for.

Comment: The base (AB) of the isosceles triangle is NOT necessarily the diameter of the circle ABC. Your first diagram seems to have that assumed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can form a circle of any radius about any point.

If you used the vertex between the equal legs as the center, and a radius equal to the length of these legs, the ends of these legs would necessarily fall on the edge of said circle.

But if you pick a vertex between unequal legs, it will of course be impossible to get the end points to fall on a circle. That would be saying the circle had two different radii...

And finally, any two radii you pick (which don't fall on a straight line) can be taken as legs of another isosceles triangle when you connect their end points.